# D3 forceRadial() with nested data centered around parent

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am trying to get d3.forceRadial() to distribute nodes hierarchically around their respective parents, but when I set the the x and y parameters on the force all the nodes shoot off towards the bottom right corner and beyond with x and y values ending up in the tenthousands..

My code looks like this:

```
let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('radial', d3.forceRadial((d) => (d.distance * 100))
        .x((d) => ((d.parent && !isNaN(d.parent.x)) ? d.parent.x + d.parent.vx : 0))
        .y((d) => ((d.parent && !isNaN(d.parent.y)) ? d.parent.y + d.parent.vy : 0))
        .strength(3))
    .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => (d.entity_id)).strength(0))
    .nodes(data.nodes);
```

Where parent is a reference to the parent node and d.distance is the number of steps away from the root node. I have tried setting all node's x and y to 0 beforehand but to no avail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current version (4.13.0 at the time of the writing), `d3.forceRadial` does **not** accept a function for the `x()` and `y()` methods, despite the fact that it does accept a function for the `radius()` method.

We can see this inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/radial.js#L44-L54).

This is the code for `radius()`:

```
force.radius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (radius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ :
        constant(+_), initialize(), force) : radius;
};
```

As you can see, it accepts a function.

But this is the code for `x()` and `y()`:

```
force.x = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (x = +_, force) : x;
};

force.y = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (y = +_, force) : y;
};
```

As you can see, it **does not** accept a function.

You can also see that the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#radial_x) only talks about numbers, not functions. Regarding `radial.x`:

> If x is specified, sets the x-coordinate of the circle center to the specified **number** and returns this force. (emphasis mine)

The same goes for `radial.y`.

Comment: Ah! I should probably have found that in my searches, but in any case I'll probably write a custom version of forceRadial()..